# Unwarranted Factor of t in Particular Solution

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

> $y'' + 3y' + 2y = t^2e^{-2t}$

The associated homogeneous solution is $y_h = Ce^{-2t} + De^{-t}$.  My understanding is that a product of any number of functions, which are each termwise-proportional to their own derivatives, is itself termwise-proportional to its own derivative.

If this is correct, then the guess for a particular solution would be $y_p = (at^2 + bt + c)(e^{-2t})$ (the proportionality constant for $e^{-2t}$ gets lumped into $a$, $b$, and $c$).  However, this yields an inconsistent algebraic system for $a$, $b$, and $c$.  I have been told to multiply the guess by $t$ because this makes the correct terms pop out, but I don't understand why.  After checking via two different methods, I am confident that $e^{-2t}$, $e^{-t}$, and $t^2e^{-2t}$ are linearly independent.  While multiplication by $t$ works, it seems unwarranted, as this maneuver is supposed to come into play only when the associated homogeneous solution and forcing term are linearly dependent, as implied [here and in pretty much every explanation of the undetermined coefficients](http://math.colgate.edu/~wweckesser/math308Fall02/handouts/undetcoeff2.pdf).

The rule cannot be that for $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = f(t)g(t)h(t)...$, each factor in the forcing term has to be linearly independent with the associated homogeneous solution, as $y'' + 3y' + 2y = (e^{-2t})(e^{-3t})(e^{-4t})$ would serve as a counterexample.  Why is the guess in this problem multiplied by an additional factor of $t$, even though the homogeneous solution and forcing term are linearly independent?

Answer (score 3):

Problems of the form $p(D) y = q(t) e^{at}$ where $p,q$ are polynomials, $D$ is the derivative operator, and $a$ is a complex number, have a rather algorithmic way to construct the particular solution. Namely:

1. Determine the order $k$ of the zero of $p$ at $t=a$.
2. Take a particular solution of the form $t^k r(t) e^{at}$ where $r$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $q$.

In your problem, $p(t)=t^2+3t+2$ has a zero of order $1$ at $t=-2$, so you take a solution of the form $t(at^2+bt+c) e^{at}$.

Why does this extra $t^k$ come into play? A reason to start with is that if you tried to use a polynomial of the same degree as $q$, the lowest $k$ coefficients would be killed by $p(D)$, so you would have fewer free coefficients than there are coefficients in $q$. So you have to do *something* different.

But a followup question is, why does this not break entirely, i.e. why isn't $p(D) t^3 e^{at}$ a cubic times $e^{at}$ (as it would be if $p(a)$ were not zero)? You can see that by thinking of the product rule: the cubic part of $p(D) t^3 e^{at}$ is given by applying all the derivatives to the $e^{at}$, which results in a factor of $p(a)$, so that term disappears. Once any derivatives hit $t^3$, you're getting a quadratic.

A different answer for intuition is to look back at first order equations: consider that $y'-ay=e^{at}$ easily gives the factor of $t$ by using the method of integrating factors. This intuition can then be used for actual calculation by operator-factoring $p(D)$. In your example, $p(D)=(D+2)(D+1)$, so replacing $u=(D+1)y=y'+y$ results in $(D+2)u=t^2 e^{-2t}$ which can be solved by the method of integrating factors, and doing so gives the extra factor of $t$ "automatically".

Comment: Is this what's called the annihilator method?

Comment: @user10478 I think that operator factorization method is called that.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this ODE consists in reducing it to a first order ODE
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime} + 3y^{\prime} + 2y = t^{2}e^{-2t} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (y^{\prime} + y)^{\prime} + 2(y^{\prime} + y) = t^{2}e^{-2t} \Longleftrightarrow w^{\prime} + 2w = t^{2}e^{-2t}
\end{align*}

where $w = y^{\prime} + y$. Multiplying both sides by $e^{2t}$, one obtains
\begin{align*}
e^{2t}w^{\prime} + 2e^{2t}w = t^{2} \Longleftrightarrow (e^{2t}w)^{\prime} = t^{2} \Longleftrightarrow e^{2t}w = \frac{t^{3}}{3} + k \Longleftrightarrow w = \frac{t^{3}e^{-2t}}{3} + ke^{-2t}
\end{align*}

Finally, we are led to solve
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime} + y = \frac{t^{3}e^{-2t}}{3} + ke^{-2t}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on [Ian’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3349956/265466), let’s look more closely at what goes wrong when we try a particular solution of the form $py_h$, where $p$ is a polynomial in $t$ and $y_h$ a solution to the homogeneous equation: $$\begin{align} (py_h)''+3(py_h)'+2(py_h) &= (p''y_h+2p'y_h'+py_h'')+3(p'y_h+py_h')+2py_h \\
&=(y_h''+3y_h'+2y_h)p + (2y_h'+3y_h)p' + y_hp''. \end{align}$$ The first term vanishes, while $y_h$ and $y_h'$ are various linear combinations of exponentials, so we must look to $p'$ and $p''$ to produce a term in $t^2$. This means that $p$ must be at least cubic.

More generally, for the equation $p(D)y=q(t)e^{at}$, if you try $r(t)e^{at}$, where $r$ is some polynomial in $t$, the left-hand side term with the highest power of $t$ comes from $(p(D)e^{at})r$, but if $e^{at}$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation, this term vanishes. The other terms all involve derivatives of $r$, so $r$ must be a higher-degree polynomial than $q$. Ian’s answer tells you just how much higher it needs to be.